# ¿No se si estara bien mi consulta read en java, ya que ejecuto en netbeans me dan error?

Tags: java, mysql

ese es mi codigo en java; mi read no se si estara bien.
Tambien no reconoce mis datos que estan en la base de datos mysql.
mi read eh intentado con select * from cliente me muestra los datos solamente de clientes pero no los de ciudadID, ni comunaID en tabla correspondiente. abajo las uni las tablas y me da el error.

```
(clase ClienteDAO)
public Conexion conex = new Conexion();
public static final String CREATE="insert into cliente values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
public static final String READ="select clienteRut, clienteNombre,clienteDireccion,"
                                +"clienteGiro,ci.ciudadID,co.comunaID from cliente c"
                                +"inner join ciudad ci on ci.ciudadID = c.ciudadID,"
                                +"inner join comuna co on co.comunaID = co.comunaID";

public static final String UPDATE = "update cliente set clienteNombre=?,clienteDireccion=?,"
                                   +"clienteGiro=?,Contacto=? where clienteRut=?";
public static final String DELETE = "delete from cliente where clienteRut=?";

public void insertar(String clienteRut, String clienteNombre, String clienteDireccion,
                        String clienteGiro,int ciudadID, int comunaID){
    conex.conectar();
    conex.preparaSQL(CREATE);
    conex.definirString(1, clienteRut);
    conex.definirString(2, clienteNombre);
    conex.definirString(3, clienteDireccion);
    conex.definirString(4, clienteGiro);
    conex.definirInt(5,ciudadID);
    conex.definirInt(6, comunaID);
    conex.ejecutarUpdate();
    conex.desconectar();
}
```

mi error que sale es:
se agradece la ayuda

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join comuna co on co.comunaID = co.comunaID' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)

Comment: Muestra la consulta SQL en algún sitio (System.out.println, log, lo que sea) y deberías ver el error directamente.

Comment: https://ibb.co/M2T87fj hay esta

Comment: No, me refiero al valor que pones en READ y que te da el error...

Comment: https://ibb.co/dm33bZs
https://ibb.co/Ytd951v

Comment: `inner join comuna co on co.comunaID = co.comunaID`, fíjate en la igualdad que has puesto... `on co.comunaID = co.comunaID` estás intentando comparar con el mismo campo dos veces. Por cierto, cuando te pidan que añadas algo a tu pregunta, no nos pongas enlaces a sitios raros, en SO tienes todo lo que necesitas en el editor de preguntas, simplemente edítala y añade el texto de los errores, o si necesitas usar una imagen puedes usar el servicio de subida de imágenes de SO, que además de funcionar muy bien, nos las guarda durante todo el tiempo que necesitemos, gratis.

Comment: "inner join ciudad ci on c.ciudadID = ci.ciudadID,"
                                    +"inner join comuna co on c.comunaID = co.comunaID" listo, pero tampoco me da el error

Comment: lo siento no sabia, prestare atencion a las sigts preguntas o comentarios futuros, gracias por la aclaracion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El detalle está en las siguientes líneas.

Reemplaza esto.

```
   public static final String READ="select clienteRut, clienteNombre,clienteDireccion,"
                                    +"clienteGiro,ci.ciudadID,co.comunaID from cliente c"
                                    +"inner join ciudad ci on ci.ciudadID = c.ciudadID,"
                                    +"inner join comuna co on co.comunaID = co.comunaID";
```

por esto:

```
public static final String READ="select c.clienteRut, c.clienteNombre,c.clienteDireccion,"
                                +"c.clienteGiro,ci.ciudadID,co.comunaID from cliente c"
                                +"inner join ciudad ci on ci.ciudadID = c.ciudadID,"
                                +"inner join comuna co on co.comunaID = c.comunaID";
```

Ojo:
No entiendo por que hacer esto

```
 "inner join ciudad ci on ci.ciudadID = c.ciudadID,"
                                 "inner join comuna co on co.comunaID = c.comunaID";
```

Ya que estas devolviendo lo siguiente: ci.ciudadID,co.comunaID, estos campos ya existen en la tabla de clientes, verifica si lo que quieres obtener es la descripción y no el id, en su caso la consulta tambien puede quedar.

```
public static final String READ="select clienteRut, clienteNombre,clienteDireccion,"
                                    +"clienteGiro,ciudadID,comunaID from cliente ";
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: gracias amigo me resulto, se te agradece:)

Comment: De favor si te funcionó marca la respuesta como correcta para que los demás sepan de este tipo de errores.